# auth/invalid-email: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-email)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am new to Firebase. I try to create the component for "reset password". However, every time when I type in the email address, Firebase gives me the error "auth/invalid-email". But I can log in using the email address that I use to test the "reset password" component, which shows that the email address does exist in the Firebase and is valid.

Here is my code

```
export default function ForgotPasswordButton() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

    const style = {
        position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', // width: 400,
        bgcolor: 'background.paper', border: '2px solid #000', boxShadow: 24, p: 4,
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (email !==""){
            Auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                .then(() => {
                    alert("Email has been sent to you, Please check and verify");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                    alert(`${errorCode}: ${errorMessage}`);
                });
        }else{
            alert("please write down your email");
        }
            


    };

    return (<>
            <Link href="#" variant="body2" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Forgot Password?</Link>
            <Modal
                open={isOpen}
                onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                aria-labelledby="modal-forgot-password"
            >
                <Box sx={style}>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Reset Password
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p" variant="p">
                        Tell us the email address associated with your account, and we’ll send you an email with a link
                        to reset your password.
                    </Typography>
                    <Box component="form" noValidate sx={{mt: 3}} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Grid container spacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    id="email"
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    name="email"
                                    autoComplete="email"
                                    value = {email}
                                    onChange = {(event)=>{setEmail(event.target.value)}}

                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <div className="Reset">
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="contained"
                                sx={{mt: 3, mb: 0.2}}>
                                Reset Password
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Modal>
        </>);
}
```